# How to use SMA port for RF Switch's TTL Control?

Tags: rf, switches, ttl

I am considering purchasing [this RF switch](https://www.eravant.com/55-to-71-ghz-25-db-isolation-wr-15-waveguide-v-band-reflective-spdt-pin-diode-switch) from Eravant (previously sage), and I realized many of its SPDT RF switches are using a SMA female port as the control logic input to the TTL driver, whether the driver is built-in to the switch or a separate part (as the above link). Why does the control logic use a SMA port instead of a pin (like the +/-5V, GND pins)? How should I connect it to, say, an Arduino microcontroller to toggle the switch?

Comment: Really can't say why the manufacturer chose that connector for the control input.

Comment: But, the data sheet leads something to be desired in so far as specifications go.  For Control Signal, is just says "TTL", under typical.  Does that mean Vil=0.8V (max), and Vih=2.4V (min)?  And at what currents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data sheet indicates a switching speed of 100 nS, so the control signal may contain frequencies >1 MHz, and is best conveyed with coaxial cable. Bear in mind this is a waveguide component, not a device meant for mounting on a PC board. Hence the coaxial RF style connector for it. You can buy a coaxial cable “pigtail” with an SMA male on one end, of any length you need, then connect the center conductor to a GPIO and shield to ground. Keep those leads reasonably short and you’ll be fine. Make sure the microcontroller is 5V I/O compatible; otherwise use a level shifter.

Comment: Thank you! Follow-up questions: 1) By "microcontroller is 5V I/O compatible", do you mean SMA ports require input of 5V or are you referring to the +/- 5V powering of the tag? 2) Just to double check, "shield to ground" refers to the SMA-pin pigtail right?

Comment: @Power_tile re 1) datasheet specs the driver port as TTL; that generally implies 5V logic (although there are other variants). And re 2) the pigtail end of the coax shield, yes.

Comment: @Power_tile Also you need both +5 and -5 volt DC supplies, referenced to the module’s ground. Most Arduino power supplies don’t have a -5V output so you’ll need an additional supply.

Comment: From [this wikipedia post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic#Interfacing_considerations) on TTL seems like 2V-5V can be considered as a HIGH for TTL input? I will double check with engineers at Eravant before purchasing. Also thanks for the comment on +/-5V supply - I have a TI LM27762EVM to provide low-noise +/-5V output.

Answer (score 0):

SMA is commonly used for higher frequency signals. If you don't care about how fast the switch works, you can run a coaxial cable to your Arduino and connect the signal directly to a GPIO and the shield to the Arduino ground.

Comment: But you really don't need an SMA connector for an ordinary TTL signal.  But the coax you mentioned should be OK.